# Send json in posturl webview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How can i send `JSON` post data in `WebView` to call a webservice with raw data?

This is my code,

```
fb.loadData(base64, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "base64");
```

Comment: What is a point of using the WebView for calling webservice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose this is your json:
1.

```
ReqBody : [{
                                'LoginId':'LoginId',                      
                                'pass' :'pass'                      
                            }
                        ]
```

Your pojo class will be:

```
public class ExamplePojo{
        @SerializedName("LoginId")
        private String LoginId;
        @SerializedName("pass")
        private String Password;

        //getter setter method  
          }
```

2.Using Gson serializes the specified object into its equivalent Json representation.

```
 public static String getJsonString(Object obj) throws JSONException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        if (obj != null) {
            String json = gson.toJson(obj);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);


            return jsonObject.toString();
        } else
            return "";
    }

3.Post this data(Return by getJsonString() say dataToPost ) as per your requirement
```

4.Suppose you have to send data in key value pair then add following :

```
NameValuePair dataToSend = new NameValuePair("key", dataToPost);
 postData = getQuery(dataToSend);



private String getQuery(NameValuePair params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(params.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(params.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
//        }

        return result.toString();
    }

try {
       mWebView.postUrl(URL, postData.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    OR



URL url;
            String response = "";
            try {
                url = new URL(URL);

                HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);


                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(dataToSend);

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
                int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

                if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    String line;
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        response += line;
                    }
                } else {
                    response = "";

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return response;
```

Response will be  html page which you can post on webview as following:
mWebView.loadData(response, "text/html", "utf-8");

Comment: i am use webview.posturl() then after open webview its give Disallowed key charachters

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    webView.postUrl("url", data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: Okay I will try to explain the answers and thank you for the good advice.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass jsonObject data as api body to webview, you can try this ->

HashMap<String, Object> map = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), HashMap.class);

String postdata1 = "";

int i = 1;

for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
postdata1 =
postdata1.concat(entry.getKey().concat("=").concat(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue()+"", "UTF-8")).concat(i == map.size() ? "" : "&"));
i++;
}

webView.postUrl(url, postdata1 .getBytes());

or

directly use key values like this

"KEY1="+ URLEncoder.encode(postData.getAmount().toString(), "UTF-8")+

```
                "&KEY2="+URLEncoder.encode(postData.getBackref(), "UTF-8") +

                "&KEY3="+URLEncoder.encode(postData.getCountry(), "UTF-8") +
```